# "Vision For" or "Vision Of"?

Tags: prepositions

I'd like to know which of these is more correct:

> ... a vision **of** the company for the future

or

> ... a vision **for** the company for the future

(I do realise that the phrase 'for the future' could be redundant here, so it could be changed to some other construct, such as 'for the next year' etc. 
I just want to find out which sounds better in a usage like this.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have a style choice here; the question better as 'clearer or easier to read' than 'more correct'.

"a vision for the company", IMO.

It's likely that anything after "for the company" which continues the point will be 'repetitive' to some degree.  Word choice will improve that or smooth the effect so that it flows well.  "for the future" is a bit obvious, thus jarring and likely to be seen as repetitive.  A more polished continuation may be equally repetitive, but accepted without thought.

Comment: Yeah, this is a good point regarding style. I get hung up on 'correctness' sometimes when maybe it's more about what sounds or flows better.  It's nice to have this place to ask these questions. Thanks for your answer :)

Answer (score 4):

They mean different things.

> My vision for the company [in the future]

Is what you want the company to be. (Presumably good)

> My vision of the company [in the future]

Is what you predict the company will be like. (Not necessarily good or bad.)

Comment: Sorry, I have just updated the question.
I intended to ask with 'for the future' instead of 'in the future'.
Would your answer still stand in this case?
I was thinking maybe the two 'fors' together might sound incorrect...

Comment: Makes no difference. There is no question of _incorrect_, though some might find the repetition of _for_ awkward.

Comment: @Colin, so first case is not different from "... a vision for the future of the company"?